# Sum outer product of vector plus its transpose plus a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, covariance

Please suggest efficient and robust method (memory size, numerical accuracy, computation speed) for the following matrix procedure:

**A**  +  [ **b** * transpose(**b**) ]  +  transpose( [**b** * transpose(**b**) ] )

where:

**A** is a *m*-by-*m* dense rank-deficient symmetric (covariance) matrix

**b** is a *m*-by-1 vector

- denotes matrix multiplication

1000 < *m* < 50000

Implementation will be in R

Comment: `X <- b %*% t(b);  A + X + t(X)` ?